# I have a ruby on rails web application work at port 3000 I want to make it works at port 80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis, port

I have a ruby on rails web application work at port 3000  I want to make it works at port 80
What is the easiest way to make it happend ?

I've tried to change port 3000 in file

> C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32\bin\mongrel_rails

But every thing crashed up so i've changed it back to 3000

Comment: Maybe port 80 is occupied already? Anyway, try this: `rails server -p 80`.

Comment: Also, why are you using 1.8.7? It's officially deprecated and won't be supported by next rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using rails 1.8.7. you should do like this `mongrel_rails start -p  80`

you  can also find more available options by doing `mongrel_rails start -h`

Comment: your right its do start -80 but its the same error that i faced when i'd changed it manuali in mongrel config file

Comment: C:\FedenaProject>bundle exec mongrel_rails start -p 80
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:80
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel/t
cphack.rb:12:in `initialize_without_backlog': Permission denied - bind(2) (Errno
::EACCES)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../
lib/mongrel/tcphack.rb:12:in `initialize'

Comment: it says the port is used but I have nothing except this bundle to run a web app.

Comment: If port 80 is already used, you should find which app is using port 80, and kill that app. you can use `netstat -b -n –a` to find the app's PID, and then use `ntsd -c q -p [app-PID]` to kill that app. Hope this can help you

Answer (score 2):

you can specify the desired port with the -p parameter

```
rails s -p 80
```

Comment: your right its do start -80 but it gives the same error that i faced when i'd changed it manuali in mongrel config file 
 
C:\FedenaProject>bundle exec mongrel_rails start -p 80 ** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:80 C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel/t cphack.rb:12:in initialize_without_backlog': Permission denied - bind(2) (Errno ::EACCES) from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../ lib/mongrel/tcphack.rb:12:in initialize'

Comment: probably you have another process listening on port 80; Camel Song wrote, in a comment on the 1st answer, how to find it and kill it